# Does not load my external JavaScript most of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have an issue with my website. I have my website created with Node, Express, MongoDB and Angular. This works fine. Now I want to use some JavaScript functions and I have created an external JavaScript file. In Chrome the JavaScript functions work fine, but when I try Mozilla browser or the mobile version of Mozilla, Chrome or Safari it does usually not load my JavaScript file. Sometimes it does. I have tried changing the order of scripts in my jade file and also excluding some other scripts, but can't seem to figure out what the problem is. It is the scripts.js file that does not work.

This is my Jade file that is rendered by Express:

```
html
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    <!-- CSS  -->
    <!-- load bootstrap & font awesome -->
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/slick.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/slick-theme.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/font-awesome.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/grid.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/styles.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/nav.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/responsive.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/colors.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/slicknav.css")

    <!-- JS  -->
    <!-- load angular, ngRoute, ngAnimate  -->
    script(type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js")
    script(type="application/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-route.js")
    script(type="application/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-animate.js")
    script(type="application/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js")
    script(type="application/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
    script(type="application/javascript" src="/javascripts/app.js")
    script(type="application/javascript" src="/javascripts/controller.js")
    script(type="application/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.slicknav.min.js")
    script(type="application/javascript" src="/javascripts/slick.js")
    script(type="application/javascript" src="/javascripts/scripts.js")
    base(href="/")

body(ng-app="loodgietersApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl")

   div(id="fb-root")
   script.
     (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  window.___gcfg = {lang: 'nl'};
  (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
   })();

div(class="app-container")
  div(ng-include="'partials/includes/nav-bar-desktop.html'")
  div(class="slider-image")
    div(class="call-us")
      span(class="phone-icon fa fa-phone fa-3x")
      span(class="phonenumber")
        span Bel gratis: 0800 - 2400 000
      span(class="available")
        span 24/7 bereikbaar

    div(class="logo")
      a(href="/")
        img(src="/images/loodgieters-logo.png" alt="loodgieter-logo")
      div(ng-include="'partials/includes/nav-bar-mobile.html'")

  div(ng-include="'partials/includes/usps.html'")

  div(ng-include="'partials/includes/search-plumber.html'")
  div(class="box")
    div(class="page-animate page" ng-view)

div(ng-include="'partials/includes/twitter-box.html'")

div(class="container")
  div(ng-include="'partials/includes/brands.html'")
  div(ng-include="'partials/includes/specialisations.html'")

div(ng-include="'partials/includes/footer.html'")
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Have you tried `document.head.append(po);`

Comment: I don't get any error. It just does not load

Comment: I did't try this. How do I use it?

Comment: Is the issue permanent for Mozilla or is it abrupt?

Comment: It does it all the time in Mozilla and safari. Also on mobile it does not work.

Comment: replace `   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);` with my previous line and try again